# windows 8 metro navigation issue

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

How can i navigate to a page from user-control, in windows 8 metro style xaml C# application.

**Update:
Actually this usercontrol is inside another usercontrol. The code below works fine when used in a user control, but in nested usercontrols it does not work.**

Here is my current code that is not working.

```
        var cntnt = Window.Current.Content;
        var frame = cntnt as Frame;

        if (frame != null)
        { 
            frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage1), null);
        }
        Window.Current.Activate();
```

It does not navigate to MyPage1 , but there is no exception.

Thanks

Comment: Metro "eats" many exceptions. Try debugging with "Break when an exception is thrown" turned on. For example, you may have an issue in the OnNaviagtedTo method of MyPage1.

Answer (score 2):

You should not pass null as parameter. Try just calling

```
frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage1));
```

Comment: Hi filip , can you please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190147/xaml-nested-gridview-disable-outer-grid-visual-styles