# XAML nested Gridview disable outer grid visual styles

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I am using nested Gridview (gridview inside another grid view) in Windows 8 metro application. I want to disable visual styles on all the events on outer grid, events like click, tapping, and dragging etc. 
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: First please do tell me why you would nest GridViews?

Comment: the grid is in semantic zoom zoomeoutview , problem is that when i use single grid than clicking on any item does not fire any event (item click,selection changed etc) it jsut goes to the zoomedinview on click, but when i put it in another gridview than it works fine, any ideas ?

Comment: I believe that is the expected behavior and you should not fight against the patterns or you will confuse the users and anger Microsoft. :)
The purpose of semantic zoom as I understand it is to quickly navigate in a larger set of data, not to provide to alternative views for working with that data. That's probably also why there are only two zoom levels there.

Answer (score 0):

You should not nest GridViews. It is like nesting list boxes - even if it worked - it would be confusing to the user.

Comment: thanks Filip, so how can i get the required functionality without nesting griviews.

Comment: Not sure what your desired functionality is, but I am guessing you might want to have groups within a GridView - you should look into that then as well as using more primitive controls/panels such as VariableSizedWrapGrid instead of using full GridViews. If you are looking to have a more interactive zoomed out view - you probably should not use the SemanticZoom control. It is all hard to say without knowing what you exactly want to achieve.