# page Navigation code on user control class file

Tags: windows-8, user-controls, navigation, microsoft-metro

hi anybody help how to write page navigation code for win8 metro apps in user control.
I tried with following code it is not working.

this.Frame.navigate();

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows 8 metro navigation issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970948/windows-8-metro-navigation-issue)

Answer (score 3):

If you are following an MVVM pattern with a framework like Caliburn Micro, MVVMLight, MicroMVVM then all of them provide a NavigationService of some sort which is usually used for navigation purpose. I would recommend you use that.

From the child control you can do this

```
var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
frame.Navigate(typeof (Page2));
```

Where Page2 is the page you want to navigate to.